# how to use media library in our application?

Tags: iphone

I want to use any media file from user media library in my iPhone application.  Just like we pick an image from photo library. Are there any API's for this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UIImagePickerController class. It allows you to select images from the photo library or camera.